# Android debugger not being able to connect to the process (app)

Tags: android, debugging, adb, android-debug, android-debugging

I am using Android Studio 1.5 and currently working on a project. Whenever I am trying to debug or attach the debugger to the app I am working on to fix bugs, the debugger is NOT able to connect; therefore the app freezes on the android device. Note that it randomly works and connects properly some time to time (like 2 out 10 times).
I get this error in the logs:

Error running Android Debugger (8600): Unable to open debugger port (localhost:8600): java.io.IOException "handshake failed - connection prematurally closed"
9:57:00 AM Error running Android Debugger (8600): Unable to open debugger port (localhost:8600): java.io.IOException "handshake failed - connection prematurally closed"
9:57:25 AM Adb connection Error:EOF
9:57:25 AM Connection attempts: 1

How can I fix this issue and be able to easily debug my app ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can try restarting adb.  From Android Studio, click "Terminal" (bottom of screen).  At the prompt enter: adb kill-server, then adb start-server. Try debugging again.

Comment: I tried "adb kill-server, then adb start-server" on the terminal and it still did not work.

Comment: I finally figured it out. It was a bad usb cable. After getting a brand new "gold plated" usb cable, I am no longer experiencing this issue.

Comment: Thanks! After installing SDK packages debugger didn't work. I restarted ADB.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever this happens to me, I just close the emulator or re-plug in my hardware device and Run the app. Android studio automatically restarts adb.

You can also try double clicking on adb in /android-sdk/platform-tools

Comment: I did it multiple times; but did not get it to work consistently. This is a really weird issue. I might have to reinstall the android sdk.

Comment: @ngaspama If I were you I would check with another device to rule out a bad android-sdk package, and update the phone drivers on the PC.

Comment: It was a bad usb cable for me. Problem solved now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the other solutions worked for you (as it didn't for me), I suggest to **try to do a clean reinstall of the Platform tools**.

1 - Start the standalone **SDK Manager**.

From Android Studio: Tools->Android->SDK manager, SDK Tools tab, click start standalone SDK manager.

2 - Close Android Studio.

3 - In **SDK manager**, in the **Tools folder**: check **Android SDK Platform-Tools** and click on the **Delete packages** button in bottom right corner.

4 - In **Explorer**, delete the folder android-sdk-path\platform-tools.

5 - Back in **SDK manager**: re-check **Android SDK Platform-Tools** and click on the **Install packages** button.